# "sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.InvalidSchemaName) schema does not exist" with PostgreSQL from SQLAlchemy/Flask

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

While trying to deploy live on render with PostgreSQL (name of application is MidCupid, an OKCupid clone, we defined schema name as "midcupid_schema" in our .env and environment variable) the render logs says the build failed with the following message:

sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.InvalidSchemaName) schema "midcupid_schema" does not exist
Feb 11 03:23:22 PM
Feb 11 03:23:22 PM  [SQL: TRUNCATE table midcupid_schema.matches RESTART IDENTITY CASCADE;]

"matches" is one of the (joint relationship) table names, the model file for which is as follows:

```
from .db import db, environment, SCHEMA, add_prefix_for_prod


matches = db.Table(
    "matches",
    db.Column("matched_1", db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(
        add_prefix_for_prod("users.id"))),
    db.Column("matched_2", db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(
        add_prefix_for_prod("users.id")))
)
if environment == "production":
    matches.schema = SCHEMA
```

Individual seed file for matches:

```
from app.models import db, environment, SCHEMA


def seed_matches(users):

    user1 = users[0]
    user2 = users[1]
    user3 = users[2]
    user4 = users[3]
    user5 = users[4]

    user2.matchlist_1.append(user1)
    user2.matchlist_2.append(user1)
    user3.matchlist_1.append(user1)
    user3.matchlist_2.append(user1)
    user4.matchlist_1.append(user1)
    user4.matchlist_2.append(user1)
    user5.matchlist_1.append(user1)
    user5.matchlist_2.append(user1)

    db.session.commit()


def undo_matches():
    if environment == "production":
        db.session.execute(
            f"TRUNCATE table {SCHEMA}.matches RESTART IDENTITY CASCADE;")
    else:
        db.session.execute("DELETE FROM matches")

    db.session.commit()
```

**init.py** seed file

```
from flask.cli import AppGroup
from .users import seed_users, undo_users
from .answers import seed_answers, undo_answers
from .likes import seed_likes, undo_likes
from .matches import seed_matches, undo_matches
from .pictures import seed_pictures, undo_pictures
from .profiles import seed_profiles, undo_profiles
from .questions import seed_questions, undo_questions


from app.models.db import db, environment, SCHEMA

seed_commands = AppGroup('seed')


@seed_commands.command('all')
def seed():
    if environment == 'production':
        undo_matches()
        undo_likes()
        undo_answers()
        undo_pictures()
        undo_profiles()
        undo_users()
        undo_questions()

    seed_questions()
    users = seed_users()
    seed_profiles()
    seed_pictures()
    seed_answers()
    seed_likes(users)
    seed_matches(users)

@seed_commands.command('undo')
def undo():
    undo_matches()
    undo_likes()
    undo_answers()
    undo_pictures()
    undo_profiles()
    undo_users()
    undo_questions()
```

Commands flask db init, migrate, upgrade, seed all work as expected in local environment, but not on production in render with PostgreSQL.
We tried manipulating the order of the seeds and undos, which returns the same error with a different table name, so we don't think it's the seeding order.
We also checked throughout application that SCHEMA was named/defined consistently, with helper function:

```
SCHEMA = os.environ.get("SCHEMA")

db = SQLAlchemy()

# helper function for adding prefix to foreign key column references in production
def add_prefix_for_prod(attr):
    if environment == "production":
        return f"{SCHEMA}.{attr}"
    else:
        return attr
```

We can't figure out why the "midcupid_schema" does not exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, we discovered that we were overwriting our customized env.py file with a default one everytime we ran "flask db init", which changed the code that handled SCHEMA in production. This fixed the error.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).